# Is "in (an) ever pursuit" correct English?

Tags: phrases

Was writing it naturally and wanted to double check but couldn't find any use of it on the net so now I'm doubting my language skills. Am a native speaker.

Comment: It’s certainly ungrammatical to me. Ever in pursuit, yes; in an eternal pursuit, yes. But _ever_ is not an adjective in my English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree, but it is sometimes used as part of an _adjectival phrase_. For example "the ever restless sea", "an ever hungry dog", "an ever more demanding employer". I wonder whether the OP has picked up on that usage without quite understanding the difference. More information on the context in which the OP wants to use the quoted phrase might help.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, it’s very common as an adverb modifying an attributive adjective, that’s true, and frequently written with a hyphen (an ever-changing scenery, etc.).

Comment: @BoldBen Say "constantly in ever pursuit of self-improvement."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So just switching it to "ever in pursuit" is all that's needed to be grammatical huh? Would adding a hyphen like your example to make it "ever-pursuing self-improvement" makes it ok?

Comment: @shoryuu You wouldn’t use the hyphen there, because _pursuing_ is a verbal participle, not an adjective. If you add the hyphen, you’re saying the self-improvement is ever-pursuing (pursuing what?), whereas without it, it’s someone who’s forever pursuing self-improvement.

Comment: good point. i totally dont know what i was thinking typing that. even i know that now that ive re-read it. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

"In never-ending pursuit" maybe.

Answer (score -3):

You mean ***forever pursuit***:

([The Infinite Pursuit](https://www.hackensackmeridianhealth.org/health-ambassadors/hmhe_admin/2019/04/19/the-infinite-pursuit/) - Neuroscience - Hackensack Meridian Health)

> I encourage all survivors to be in a forever pursuit to continue improving.

Comment: This still seems awkward to me, compared to "eternal pursuit" (as suggested elsewhere in comments) or "perpetual pursuit".